# Issue with TAB event in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

When user click TAB key from keyboard, some cells should be updated in the same row(Event should be happen iff there is some data in that cell). As of know I written some sample code to display some message. I written code inside the **workbook** as below

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetselectionChange (ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.OnKey"{TAB}", "sayHi"
End Sub

Sub sayHi()
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        MsgBox "Hiiii"
End Sub
```

Issue :- whenever I am clicking TAB key, getting one **warning** like **"cannot run the macro 'C:...sayHi'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled".**

Comment: Side note/question: Why do you have this inside a sheet selection change event? Workbook open seems like a better candidate.

Comment: Hi, I tried that also but facing same issue. For the sake of telling I posted one method.

Comment: Should "MagBox" be "MsgBox"?

Comment: No no this code I have written here not copied from my actual code in that I written it correctly.

Comment: The actual issue is getting warning message as mentioned below that code

Comment: You are missing the `,` in the `Application.OnKey"{TAB}"  "sayHi"`  Also make sure the `Sub sayHi()` is in a module and not `ThisWorkbook`

Comment: That is also I tried. If you don't mind can I get your whatsapp number. I can share you the screenshot.

Comment: It works for me putting the sub in a module and not `ThisWorkbook` you can [edit] your post to include a link to the photo.

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/xo62wMcTkURxJwna9

Comment: the second sub: `Sub sayHi()` should not be in `ThisWorkbook` module with the first sub.  It should be in a general module.  That is the answer to your problem.

Comment: Hi, still facing the same issue. I created new module and put that sayHi() sub in that newly created module.

Comment: Here is the link for the issue which I am getting warning https://photos.app.goo.gl/uWyxuiNwvqumgLWr6